# What will happen if the conditon in the for loop is continuously changed?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

What will be the result of the following block of code?

```
 ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
   myList.remove(i);
    }
```

The answer is provided as the loop will never run.

But for an input of [-1, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33], 
I got [3, 17, 33] as output. What does it mean?

Comment: the condition clause is evaluated on each iteration, so `myList.size()` will be call each time. Only the init clause is called once. FYI : `for(init;condition;iteration)`. In your logic, you will remove the first, third, fifth (odd index), ... element, since the next one will be shifted on the left. If you want to remove every items, simply start from the end of the list and remove the item from right to left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition is evaluated on each iteration.
At the beginning the list contains
[-1, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33]
  and the loop begins:

- i = 0; 0 < 6 is true, current list [**-1**, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33], element with index 0 (bolded) removed, remaining [3, 28, 17, 9, 33]
- i = 1; 1 < 5 is true, current list [3, **28**, 17, 9, 33], element with index 1 (bolded) removed, remaining [3, 17, 9, 33]
- i = 2; 2 < 4 is true, current list [3, 17, **9**, 33], element with index 2 (bolded) removed, remaining [3, 17, 33]
- i = 3; 3 < 3 is false, loop ends, remains [3, 17, 33]

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong!** The loop will run *as long as the conditions are still satisfied*. Every iteration will produce a new scenario and the conditions just bend around to suit the new values.

Using your example [-1, 3, 28, 17, 9, 33]:

- **First iteration:** i is 0... 0 is less than 6.. element at index `0` (-1) is hence removed

  Resultant arrraylist: [3, 28, 17, 9, 33]
- **Second iteration:** i is 1... 1 is less than 5.. element at index `1` (28) is hence removed

  Resultant arrraylist: [3, 17, 9, 33]
- **Third iteration:** i is 2... 2 is less than 4.. element at index `2` (9) is hence removed

  Resultant arrraylist: [3, 17, 33]
- **Fourth iteration:** i is 3... 3 is **not** less than 3.. Iteration stops.

After the loop operation, your MyList arraylist will be reduced to:

```
[3, 17, 33]
```

I hope this helps, merry coding!